# SSH from Ubuntu to Windows fails with “Connection reset by peer”

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh

I setup SSH server on my Windows machine from [this link](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server). SSH from Ubuntu to Windows worked fine for a while, but then it started failing with the following error. If I restart the Windows machine, it will work fine for a while and then start failing again. What is going wrong?

```
user@hostname:~$ ssh user@ip
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

user@hostname:~$ ssh -v user@ip
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ssh/2926/debugging-ssh-problems/25954/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer#t=201707181925180779665

Comment: Restarting sshd service on the Windows machine resolved the problem for now. Any pointers on how to avoid this?